The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Login"} was not handled by any navigator
Here is my codes:
import "./global.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { AppStore, makeStore } from "./src/reduxStore/store";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import LoginScreen from "./src/screens/auth/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "./src/screens/auth/RegisterScreen";
import MainScreen from "./src/screens/protected/MainScreen";

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Login: undefined;
  Register: undefined;
  Main: undefined;
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

const AuthScreensStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Login"
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const ProtectedScreenStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Main"
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const MainApp = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState<boolean | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("app loaded");
    const handleUserData = async () => {
      const userLoginFlag = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");
      setIsLoggedIn(userLoginFlag === "true");
    };
    handleUserData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isLoggedIn ? <ProtectedScreenStack /> : <AuthScreensStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore | null>(null);
  if (storeRef.current === null) {
    storeRef.current = makeStore();
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={storeRef.current}>
      <MainApp />
    </Provider>
  );
}



import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { NavigationProp, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { RootStackParamList } from "../../../App";

export default function MainScreen({ navigation }: any) {
  // const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProp<any>>();

  const handleLogOut = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("logout api called");
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn");
      navigation.navigate("Login");

      // navigation.reset({
      //   index: 0,
      //   routes: [{ name: "Auth" }],
      // });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View className="flex-1 h-full bg-blue-300 justify-center items-center">
      <Text> Main page</Text>
      <Button title="Logout" onPress={() => handleLogOut()} />
    </View>
  );
}




import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { NavigationProp, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { RootStackParamList } from "../../../App";

export default function LoginScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>();

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("login api called");
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", JSON.stringify(true));
      navigation.navigate("Main");
      // navigation.reset({
      //   index: 0,
      //   routes: [{ name: "Main" }],
      // });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View className="flex-1 h-full bg-blue-300 justify-center items-center">
      <Text>Login page</Text>
      <Button title="Login" onPress={() => handleSubmit()} />
      <Button
        title="Register"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Register")}
      />
    </View>
  );
 }

I'm reaching out to seek assistance with a challenge I'm facing in my React Navigation implementation.
I've been working on setting up navigation for an authentication flow in my React Native app, and I've encountered a problem with navigating between the authentication screens and the protected screens. Specifically, I've structured my navigation using createNativeStackNavigator, and I'm trying to optimize the nesting of navigators based on best practices outlined in the React Navigation documentation.
However, despite following the recommended guidelines, I'm encountering an error message stating: "The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Login"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'Login'?
If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production."
To give you more context, here's an overview of my current setup:
I have two main stacks: AuthScreensStack for authentication screens (Login and Register), and ProtectedScreenStack for protected screens (Main).
I'm using a useState hook to determine whether the user is logged in or not, and based on this, I render the appropriate stack in my MainApp component.
The ProtectedScreenStack should only contain the MainScreen, while the AuthScreensStack should only contain the LoginScreen and RegisterScreen.
I've reviewed the React Navigation documentation and made adjustments to my code accordingly, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue. I believe I may be overlooking something or misinterpreting the documentation.
Would you be available to review my code and provide some guidance on how to properly structure the navigation to avoid the error message mentioned above? Any insights or suggestions you could offer would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Does this answer your question? ERROR The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {...} was not handled by any navigator in React Native
